# SQL Oracle Same field 1 must have one field 2 if the value of field 1 is same

Tags: sql, oracle

In a table, lets have field 1 as username and field 2 as id. If the username is same then the id field must be fetched only once at first irrespective of number of times the username is fetched. Below image i have added the example.

[image]

so whenever same user name comes its id must be coming in the first row of its respective username. Please let me know for this.

Comment: Although it will be possible to do this, is this being consumed by a downstream system? This seems like the sort of formatting decision that could be made by the downstream system.

Comment: Note that tables have _columns_, not fields.

Comment: In case you don't understand what is meant by "downstream system": SQL is meant to get the data from the database not to care about display things. You usually call the SQL from somewhere, e.g. a website or an app. If you want the data to be presented in a certain format, then deal with this there, not in the SQL query.

Comment: By the way: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1):

As I noted in the comments, formatting the data like this might be better done in a consuming system downstream.

However, you could likely do something like:

```
SELECT 
 "USER", 
 CASE WHEN row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY "USER", id ORDER BY 1) = 1 THEN id END id
FROM test
ORDER BY "User", id
```

You can see it working [in this Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/3ifVb_qY).

The `row_number()` window function will assign a number to each row, starting at 1 for each group of `user`/`id` (because of the `partition by`). This is then used by the `case` to determine what to display.

Note that as per comments, my original solution only guaranteed that one of the rows per `user` would have the `id` populated (not necessarily the first one). I have updated my solution with `ORDER BY "USER", id` in this post and the Fiddle. I've also added Thorsten Kettner's alternate to the Fiddle.

Comment: Not quite. Without an order by clause the rows can be shown in any order. While the result in your fiddle happens to get ordered as desired, this is in no way guaranteed. And with an `ORDER BY "USER", id` there will still be no deterministic order to always make the row showing the ID the first of the group. Use `PARTITION BY "USER", id ORDER BY rowid` instead, and add `ORDER BY "USER", id, rowid` at the end of your query.

Comment: Fair point. I was thinking that wouldn't be an issue since I'm literally using `row_number` but I see you are correct because of my arbitrary `order by` in the window function. I think `ORDER BY "User", id` is sufficient, though, since the non-null id will end up first.

Comment: No, that doesn't suffice. If you order the three rows AAA|1011, AAA|1011, and AAA|1011 by "USER" and id only, which would come first, which second and which third? They all look the same, and the window clause may order them differently from your query's `ORDER BY` clause. You need something that makes the order deterministic, for which using the ROWID is the easiest solution.

Comment: I think you're confused (or I am!). The query's `order by` clause refers to the _calculated_ `id`, and there will only be one non-null calculated `id` per `user`. It will always put the non-null one before the null ones. There's no need for the `order by` in the window function to be deterministic so long as the query's `order by` is deterministic.

Comment: Ah, sorry, you are right. The calculated column `id` has precedence over the table column `id` in the `ORDER BY` clause. I missed that.